# Javascript function inside Django Loop runs only once

Tags: javascript, django

In my template, i generate each table row within a django for loop,
I have this function that formats strings the way I want, but it's working only in the first row of the table, I dont know why.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem is basically that in HTML you can't have two elements with the same id, and you are calling them `cpfpg` then is logic that the first row is ok because you have only one element with that id but after that you have more than one element with the same id and that's the problem.

I think you can change it `id="cpfpj{{forloop.counter}}"` then you can do in your javascript:

```
ele = document.getElementById("cpfpj{{forloop.counter}}")
```

It just fix your problem.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, I used {{ forloop.counter }} to handle that

Comment: Well I was writing the solution but you did it....

Comment: I did it! Because of your advice

Comment: Great solution! Worked like a charm for me. {{ forloop.counter }} can be pretty useful!